# Oracle: Read from CLOB column line by line and insert to the table

Tags: oracle

I have CLOB column, and wanna read its data line by line to insert it in another table.

Now let's create the same situation that I have:

Data in a Table **MyTable_1**

```
OWNER | TABLE_NAME | SQL
----------------------------
HR    | AAA        | <CLOB>
```

In `<CLOB>` there is the following data:

```
CREATE TABLE AAA
( A NUMBER
);
```

I want my table to look like this(let's call it **MyTable_2**) :

```
OWNER | TABLE_NAME | SQL
----------------------------
HR    | AAA        |CREATE TABLE AAA
HR    | AAA        |( A NUMBER
HR    | AAA        |);
```

Comment: See [here](http://www.orafaq.com/forum/mv/msg/146078/406753/0/#msg_406753)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a full answer because it only works if your `clob` is less than 4000 chars. The clob version (with plain `bar` instead of `to_char(bar)` in the query) fails with `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB` - perhaps someone else can explain why exactly?

testbed:

```sql
drop table foo;
create table foo(id integer, bar clob);
insert into foo(id, bar) values (1, 'Hello'||chr(10)||'there');
insert into foo(id, bar) values (2, 'Hello'||chr(10)||'there'||chr(10)||'again');
```

query:

```sql
with w(id, line#, line, rest) as (
  select id, 1, regexp_substr(to_char(bar), '^.*?$', 1, 1, 'm'), 
         substr(to_char(bar), regexp_instr(bar, '$', 1, 1, 1, 'm')+1)
  from foo
  union all
  select id, line#+1, regexp_substr(rest, '^.*?$', 1, 1, 'm'), 
         substr(rest, regexp_instr(rest, '$', 1, 1, 1, 'm')+1)
  from w
  where rest is not null ) cycle id, line# set is_cycle to '1' default '0'
select id, line#, line from w order by id, line#;
/*
ID                     LINE#                  LINE                                     
---------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------------------------- 
1                      1                      Hello                                    
1                      2                      there                                    
2                      1                      Hello                                    
2                      2                      there                                    
2                      3                      again                                    
*/
```

Comment: nb this is 11g+ only due to the recursive `with`. Also regex is not the only/fastest approach, just what I'm used to.

Comment: I got the following error: 
ORA-32033: unsupported column aliasing
on "with w("

Comment: sorry! it is a [new 11gR2](http://rwijk.blogspot.com/2009/11/recursive-subquery-factoring.html) feature, not 11g as I thought